# Dialog open in Javascript function don't allow selection of file

Tags: javascript, html, input, dom-events

I have this button in my page:

```
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="edit_arquivo(event,this);">
          <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
        </button>
```

with a Javascript function associated to it, where I want open a dialog to choose a file to upload to the server after. I have this code to open the dialog:

```
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type="file";
  input.click();
```

which works for opening the dialog, but also I notice that after that, the code keeps being executed or something, and in the next part:

```
var file = input.files[0];
let name = file.name.split('.')[0] + '_' + (type=='versaoPaga'? 'pro' : 'lite');
let ext = file.name.split('.').pop();
```

I got an error, because `input.files[0]` is returning undefined, since I do not have time to select a file in the dialog in the screen (even if I select and click ok, doesn't matter anymore, no action is executed after that error).

To try avoid that, I also  try:

```
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.type="file";
  input.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });
  input.click();
```

which give me the same result.

Anyone can give a hint about the right way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...but also I notice that after that, the code keeps being executed or something...

Yes, it does. Calling `click` doesn't stop the JavaScript code and make it wait for the user to pick a file. Web development is all about *responding to events*. In this case, the event is the user picking a file:

```
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type="file";
input.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var file = input.files[0];
    let name = file.name.split('.')[0] + '_' + (type=='versaoPaga'? 'pro' : 'lite');
    let ext = file.name.split('.').pop();
});
input.click();
```